# GraphicksMagic: white -> transparent

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, graphicsmagick, node-imagemagick

I found many forum posts about this but none of what I found could solve it for me:

I need to convert the white background of images like the one attached to transparent using GraphicsMagick (or ImageMagick). But when I run any of the below commands, the background becomes black instead of transparent.

In GraphicsMagick I tried:

```
gm convert input.png -opaque white output.png
gm convert input.png -fill transparent -opaque white output.png
gm convert input.png -background transparent -opaque white output.png
gm convert input.png -background transparent -fill transparent -opaque white output.png
```

[image]

My application is in nodeJS so a nodeJS solution using the GM package would be even better;

```
gm('input.png')
    .dosomething()
    .write('output.png');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image does not already have an alpha channel, so use `-matte`:

```
gm convert input.png -matte -fill transparent -opaque white output.png
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it even more simply:

```
gm convert wave.png -transparent white result.png
```